# Display menu items in two columns - MUI Menu

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React. I am using MUI menu to display items in two columns. When i use the grid display with repeat 2 and 1fr i notice a big space between menu items.

```
display:'grid' , gridTemplateColumns : 'repeat(2, 1fr)'
```

The space can be reduced after setting the width but it then wrap the text as shown on the last screenshot below.

Is there a way to remove that gap and have the menu item with based on content length.

Here is the code from the tsx file;

```
 const MenuGroupSection = ({ label, groups, menuVariant, onItemClick }: 
  MenuGroupSectionProps) => {
  return (
    <Stack direction="column" sx={{ display: 'flex', width: '100%' }}>
      {label !== undefined && label !== null ? (
        <>
          <Box sx={{ margin: '16px', marginBottom: '8px' }}>
            <Typography variant="body2semibold" sx={{ color: '#000000' }}>
              {label}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
      <Stack direction="row" sx={{width: '60%', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: '5px', display:'grid' , gridTemplateColumns : 'repeat(2, 1fr)' }}>
        {groups &&
          groups.map((group, index) => {
            return (
              <MenuItemGroup
                key={index}
                label={group.label}
                items={group.items as MenuItemNode[]}
                onItemClick={onItemClick}
                menuVariant={menuVariant}
              ></MenuItemGroup>
            );
          })}
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

Here is the before screen shot;

[image]

Here is the after screen shot with display:'grid' , gridTemplateColumns : 'repeat(2, 1fr)'

[image]

Here is the screenshot after adding width 350px with display:'grid' , gridTemplateColumns : 'repeat(2, 1fr)'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You divided the row in two equal columns, while the text in the left side is shorter than the right side a white space will be there. You can try you add `auto` before the `repeat` like this `gridTemplateColumns : 'auto repeat(1, 1fr)` that `auto` will make the width of each column be auto and it will take the largest content width. Also if you want the `text` not break or wrap to new line you can add CSS property to the text `whiteSpace: nowrap`

Comment: auto repeat(2, 1fr) did not work. It shows three columns now not 2.

Comment: I have updated my answer, change the `2` to `1`, because the `auto` is a column and `repeat()` is how many columns more you want to add in the same row.